# a limit of integrals with floor function

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

i need an idea to calculate the limits of  $$\frac{1}{n}\int_{-n}^n f(x) \cos(\pi x) dx$$
where  f is definded by

$f(x)=x-\lfloor x\rfloor$ if  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an odd number

$f(x)=1-(x-\lfloor x\rfloor)$ if  $\lfloor x\rfloor$ is an even number

I have no idea ! please dont close

Comment: $\lfloor x \rfloor$ is an integer for any real $x$ so it can be odd or even. (this was in response to a comment about how can an arbitrary real be odd or even).

Comment: question edited, 
I dont understand what you mean

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two tricks:

First break up into two cases, and consider each unit interval separately.  For example, for even $\lfloor x \rfloor$ you have 
$$
\int_{x = 2k}^{2k+1}(x - \lfloor x \rfloor) \cos (\pi x) dx
$$

Second trick:  Replace $x$ in each interval by a variable which goes from $0$ to $1$. In the example, let $r = x - 2k$ to get
$$
\int_{r = 0}^{1}r \cos (\pi (r+2k )) dr
$$
In each case, $\cos (\pi (r+2k )) = \cos (r + 2k\pi) = \cos r$ so all the integrals for all values of $k$ are the same:
$$\int_0^1 r\cos(\pi r) dr$$
This integral is easy by Integration By Parts, and gives some value like $2$.

Do the same for odd $\lfloor x \rfloor$ , where the integral goes from $2k+1$ to $2k+2$.  Again you will find they are all the same.

Now add the contributions of these intervals in pairs, and you will find how fast the integral grows with $n$.  The result will be something proportional to $n$ and the division by $n$ gives you the answer (which might be zero if the intervals cancel in pairs).

Comment: now i see,  thanks